# Find the difference between elements in an array and store the results in a new array

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, element

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int index_x[] = {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0};      // any number of elements
int len = sizeof index_x / sizeof*index_x;

int main(void) {

    int arr[len];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (index_x[i])
            arr[j++] = i;                     // save and advance j only if value is "1"

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)               // only print below j !
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
8
11
```

From this output, I would like to generate another array that is the difference between these elements. In this case the new array would be {2,4,3}. (2-4=2, 8-4=4, 11-8=3).

I am currently struggling with two things:

1. Saving the array generated from the current code `arr[i]` as a another array so I can manipulate it for future uses.
2. Generating the "differences array". The tricky part is that the number of elements will not be constant so I cannot specify an array size.

Comment: perhaps you could declare 2 arrays in your function? (memcpy, malloc are also options)

Comment: Will not the "differences" array always be `j - 1` in length?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I misunderstood the problem, here. Is your concern about optimization of execution time, or optimization of array lengths (or something else)? The answer I posted will do what (I think) you want but there are better ways to do it if the source array is likely to be (very) large and speed and memory usage are concerns.

Comment: Also, will your source data array only ever contain `0` and `1` values?

Comment: @AdrianMole Yup only 0 and 1 values

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to break things out into functions.

```
int indexes_of_non_zero(int *source, size_t len, int **dest) {
    *dest = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (source[i] != 0) {
            (*dest)[count++] = i;
        }
    }

    *dest = realloc(*dest, sizeof(int) * count);

    return count;
}
```

So we have a function `indexes_of_non_zero` that takes a source array of ints with size specified by argument `len`, and then a pointer to an array of ints that will be the destination for our output.

We can naively allocate the same amount of memory to the destination, then loop over the source array and store the indexes of non-zero elements. When we're done, we use `count` to know the size of destination array. We use `realloc` to shrink the array to just the needed size. And the key is we return the count so our `main` function knows how big the destination array is.

We can now create a `diffs` function to do basically the same thing for the differences.

```
int diffs(int *source, size_t len, int **dest) {
    *dest = malloc(sizeof(int) * (len - 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < (len - 1); i++) {
        (*dest)[i] = abs(source[i] - source[i + 1]);
    }

    return len - 1;
}
```

Putting it all together (not copying and pasting the function implementations for terseness) with a `main` function, and remembering to free the memory we've used, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int indexes_of_non_zero(int *source, size_t len, int **dest);
int diffs(int *source, size_t len, int **dest);

int main(void) {
    int data[] = {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0};
    size_t len = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);

    int *nz = NULL;
    int *d = NULL;
    int nzc = indexes_of_non_zero(data, len, &nz);
    int dlen = diffs(nz, nzc, &d);

    for (int i = 0; i < nzc; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", nz[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dlen; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", d[i]);
    }

    free(nz);
    free(d);
}
```

And compiling and running it, the output is:

```
2
4
8
11
2
4
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to get the differences as direct as possible; the inner loop is very simple.

The size question, first part: I (still) tried to avoid `size_t` for the input but added some sanity check for the size. Just to show there *is* a limit.

part two: a first loop to get the sum of true values in advance. Also the `booldata` array consists of chars and is not called `index_x`. Index is `i`.

part three: the `diffs` VLA gets its exact size, which can be 0 even for huge inputs. Some test could be added here after counting, to rule out a (big) input full of "1".

I added the copying, with message and printout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char booldata[] = { 0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0 };

char sz_overf = sizeof booldata > 0xffffL * 0xffff;   // too-big-flag for exiting...       
int len = sizeof booldata / sizeof * booldata;        // ...to keep len below size_t   

int sum_of_trues (char *booldata, int len) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (booldata[i])
            sum++;
    return sum;
}

void print_intarr(int *inta, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d\n", inta[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    if (sz_overf) return 100;                // len might be overflowed    
    int unsigned                             // signed provokes VLA warning: 9 gazillions seems ok, but not 18  
    dsum = sum_of_trues(booldata, len) - 1;  // Invest a counting loop 

    int diffs[dsum],                         // VLA
        di = 0;                              // diffs' index
    int sti = -1;                            // Stored last index containing true

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)

        if (booldata[i]) {               // true?

            if (sti >= 0) {              // and is there a left neighbour?
                int diff = i - sti;         // how far away?
                printf("%d\n", diff);       // 1. on-the-fly result
                diffs[di++] = diff;         // 2. for keeps   
            }
            sti = i;                     // remember last "true" 
        }

    printf("Copying %zu bytes from Diff.-Array\n", sizeof diffs);

    int diffscopy[sizeof diffs];
    memcpy(diffscopy, diffs, sizeof diffs);
    print_intarr(diffscopy, dsum);               // dsum or sizeof diffs


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2
4
3
Copying 12 bytes from Diff.-Array
2
4
3
```

The inner loop could look like this w/o multi-option:

```
if (booldata[i]) {
    if (sti >= 0)                     // and is there a left neighbour?
        diffs[di++] = i - st;         // 2. for keeps   
    sti = i;
}
```

Two arrays and three variables. The rest is needed to make this work.

BUGS: all-false input segfaults. It takes one "true" to get zero diffs...